# Почему при наследовании от дженериков не наследуются ограничения?

Tags: c#, .net

Почему при наследовании от дженериков не наследуются все ограничения и в итоге приходится тянуть портянку ограничений при наследовании.

В этом есть какой-то сакральный смысл по которому майрософт не стала давать эту возможность? Вроде, не продублировав ограничений компилятор будет ругаться => нету возможности на уровнях выше ставить альтернативные ограничения.

```
class Generic1<T> where T : class { }
class Generic2<T> : Generic1<T> where T : class { }
```

Comment: Пример добавьте

Comment: @АндрейNOP Добавил

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/15/why-are-generic-constraints-not-inherited/

Answer (score 9):

Сакральный смысл в том, что C# - язык с прямым порядком вывода типов, а не обратным.

К примеру, в выражении `double x = 1 / 2` под оператором `/` понимается целочисленное деление, а не вещественное - потому что операторы целочисленные. Язык не умеет выводить тип операндов исходя из предполагаемого типа результата.

Также и для типов. Ограничения на параметры-типы - это их типы. Базовый класс - вычисляемое выражение. Тип вычисляемого выражения определяется исходя из типов операндов, а наоборот нельзя.

---

Вы просто привыкли к простейшим формам наследования - `Foo<T> : Bar<T>`. Но ведь можно написать и так: `Foo<A, B> : Bar<Baz<A, B>.C>`. Какие ограничения откуда должны наследоваться в подобных случаях? По-идее, надо унаследовать ограничения класса Baz. Но это будет уже обратный вывод типа.

Comment: _"Язык не умеет выводить тип операндов исходя из предполагаемого типа результата"_ - кажется, лямбы с тобой не согласны...

Comment: @Qwertiy: Скорее не "не умеет выводить", а "не выводит". Не потому, что глупый, а потому, что так решил.